# CSS selector: presence of a global attribute with any value

Tags: css

Is there a way to have a CSS selector matching *any* value for an attribute, as long as the attribute is present?

Example:

```
html {
    background: white // no 'lang' attribute is present
}

html:lang(en-US) {
    background: red; // specific 'lang' attribute value
}

html:lang(*) {
    background: green; // 'lang' attribute is present - covers all other values besides 'en-US'
}
```

I tried the above `:lang(*)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) will do this.

```css
[lang] { /* any element with lang attribute */
  background: red;
}

[lang='en'] {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div>No lang</div>
<div lang="en">en</div>
<div lang="fr">fr</div>
<div>No lang</div>
```

Comment: Ah, facepalm!!! Thank you.